# Set specific plugins per Cordova platform

Tags: cordova, plugins, config, platform

I'm using cordova latest version (5.X.X) to build an multi platform app (ios/android/wp8).
In the "main/root" config.xml I have some plugins dependencies specified:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-datepicker" spec="~0.8.6" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~3.0.0" />
```

But I need to add only specif plugins per platform.
For example in wp8 use "X" plugin and in iOS platform use "Y" plugin.

I tried to set the plugin dependencies inside the platform, with out luck:

```
<platform name="wp8">
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>

    <plugin name="some-plugin-name" spec="version_number" />

</platform>
```

How can I do this?

Or, is there other way? Can I have multiple plugins "A, B, C, D" installed, and when adding a platform only include "A, B, D"?

I know I can add/del the plugins manually, but it's a very big project with some different people working on it, and if I could create some automatic process it would be great.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, if the plugin support the platform it will be installed

Comment: I was trying to do it using the <hook>. In the docs it says it is possible set a hook per platform: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_hooks_index.md.html

I already have a script to install the correct plugins each time a platform is added, but it doesn't run if is set on the platform, only outside:

<hook type="before_platform_add" src="hooks/HookInstallPlugins.js" />

Comment: I tried it as well today with Cordova 6.2.0, seems like it's not supported yet.